# Undo Java Script onclick function after resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I'm trying to make content display on click but ONLY under a screen width of 700px. If the user presses the button and resizes their window, the content disappears.

Basically, my code looks something like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dropdownContent = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');
  var landing = document.getElementById('landing');

  const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)')

  if (dropdownContent.style.display == "none" && mediaQuery.matches) {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    landing.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    landing.style.display = "block";
    dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  #dropdown-content {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #dropdown-content {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">About</button>
<div id="dropdown-content" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="landing"></div>
```

I tried working with media queries or various "window.innerwidth" sort of things, but nothing seems to be working! I guess the javascript changes all of the "display:none" to "display:block," but I'm only trying to toggle the "display:none" under **@media only screen and (max-width: 700px)**.

Comment: _'I guess the javascript changes all of the "display:none" to "display:block,"'_ - it sets _inline_ style, and that has a higher _specificity_ than any of your media query rules.

Comment: You should handle this using classes, instead of by manipulating inline styling. Dynamically add or remove a class, say `show` - and in your stylesheet, put `#dropdown-content.show { display: block; }` into the relevant media query only.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `CSS` is OK. The `display: none` in the media query will ensure that #dropdown-content is not visible initially on smaller screens.

```
//JavaScript Function for Toggle:
function myFunction() {
  var dropdownContent = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');
  var landing = document.getElementById('landing');
  const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)');

  if (mediaQuery.matches) {
    dropdownContent.style.display = (dropdownContent.style.display === "none" || !dropdownContent.style.display) ? "block" : "none";
    landing.style.display = (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") ? "none" : "block";
  }
}

//JavaScript for Window Resize Event:

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var dropdownContent = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');
  var landing = document.getElementById('landing');
  const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 700px)');

  if (!mediaQuery.matches) {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    landing.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```